# How can I split my measure into different columns by month in Business Objects WebI?

Tags: business-objects

This task is to be completed using SAP Business Objects WebI 4.2.
I have a table in the following format:
Company     Date     Amount
A          1/1/2014    100
A          16/2/2014   400

I have a variable called Month that has the Month for each transaction.

I want the table to look like:
Company     January     February
A            100          400

How can this be done without making a calculated field for each month?

Answer (score 0):

In Webi you can't easily place a distinct category (Company) next to the values of another category (Month) in the same header row. So you have two options:

1) Create a regular horizontal table with three columns: Company, Month, & Value
2) Create a crosstab table with the Company on the left/vertical axis and the Month on the top/horizontal axis. Your values would be in the middle.

Note: if you wanted to do a lot of manual coding, you could set it up the way you want. The first column would hold your Company variable. The next column, "January" would require a formula:

```
=if([Month]=January) Then [Value]
```

You'd then have to create 11 more columns, with variables for each:

```
=if([Month]=February) Then [Value]

=if([Month]=March) Then [Value]

=if([Month]=April) Then [Value]
```

etc...

It would be tedious to do, and personally I'd go for one of the first two options. But it would work!